# Wordpress thumbnail don't show in home page

Tags: wordpress, thumbnails

After udating wordpress to the last version my website don't show thumbnail please i need a solution
my website: [Linux Demo](http://www.linuxdemo.com/)

I'm using WP Video Robot plugin and automated video importer, but before the wordpress update it was working fine

Answer (score 0):

You need to find the root cause of whether the theme or any of the plugins installed is causing the issue.

Deactivate the plugins and change the theme to a twenty sixteen or other WP theme and see if the features work.

If yes than activate one plugin at a time and see if things still work and if yes after all plugins reactivated then the theme might need an upgrade and if the plugin has failed then it needs an upgrade.

If you don't see an upgrade in the coming few days then you might have to think of replacing the broken theme or plugin.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i followed your instructions but also with twenty sixteen theme it still the same problem

Comment: did you deactivate all your plugins and check ?